# Expressing Gamma Function as an euler constant

Tags: calculus, limits, gamma-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

Q. Use the definition $$ \Gamma(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!n^x}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)} $$ in this problem.

a) Show that $ \Gamma (x+1) = x\Gamma(x) $ for $ x>0 $

b) First, express $\mathbb{ln}\Gamma(x)$ as sum  of terms.
Then, differentiate to show that $$\Gamma'(1) = -\gamma$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.

For part a), I tried putting $(x+1)$ into the expression given and tried to simplify, but I didn't get much far. Same for multiplying x to the definition as well.
For part b), I am completely lost as I do not know how to express $\mathbb{ln}\Gamma(x)$ as a sum of terms.

Answer (score 3):

a) Separate out the required terms for the expression for x
$$
\frac{n!n^{x+1}}{(x+1)(x+1)\dots(x+1+n)}
=
\frac{n!n^x}{x(x+1)\dots(x+n)}\cdot\frac{nx}{x+n+1}
$$
Both factors converge independently for $n\to\infty$.

b) The logarithmic derivative of the term under the limit is
$$
\ln(n)-\frac1x-\frac1{x+1}-\dots-\frac1{x+n}
$$
Compare with the definition of the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Now argue that you can exchange the limits of the derivative and the gamma function. The logarithm is known as continuous.